# How can i move to right by dragging the scene to the left in Corona?

Tags: drag-and-drop, coronasdk, scene

Well, i want to make levels to my game like in Angry Birds. So how can i move from left to right by dragging the scene? What should i use for this in Corona? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert all the images on the screen you want to drag (presumably everything besides any GUI objects) into a group.

From there write a function with a touch listener assigned to the group itself. It would look something like this, supposing you're app is iPhone landscape mode.

```
local function constrainMap ()
if localGroup.x < -480 then
    localGroup.x = -480
elseif localGroup.x > 0 then
    localGroup.x = 0
end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", constrainMap)

local function moveMap (event)
if event.phase == "began" then
    localX = localGroup.x
elseif event.phase == "moved" then
    localGroup.x = localX + (event.x - event.xStart)
end
end
localGroup:addEventListener("touch", moveMap)
```

In the above case the localGroup contains all visual elements and the constrainMap function is used to prevent the user from scrolling the map off the screen.